# C# LINQ question with potential group-by layers

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, linq-to-sql

I am a newbie with linq so any suggestions are very helpful. Let's say I have a dataset looks like

```
acct    dim         unit_code
10000   DIMENSION2  100
10000   DIMENSION2  1000
10000   DIMENSION2  1300
10000   DIMENSION2  1400
20000   DIMENSION2  1500
20000   DIMENSION2  200
20000   DIMENSION2  600
20000   DIMENSION2  700
20000   DIMENSION2  800
20000   DIMENSION2  900
10000   DIMENSION3  FGAC
10000   DIMENSION3  FGCP
10000   DIMENSION3  FGCV
10000   DIMENSION3  FGED
20000   DIMENSION3  FGES
20000   DIMENSION3  FGGM
20000   DIMENSION3  FGLD
20000   DIMENSION3  FGNB
20000   DIMENSION3  FGOR
20000   DIMENSION3  FGPM
10000   DIMENSION4  ENDO
20000   DIMENSION4  OTHR
20000   DIMENSION4  POTN
```

and here is my classes

```
public class RestrictionRule
{
    public string acct { get; set; }
    public List<dim> dims { get; set; }
}
public class dim
{
     public string dim { get; set; }
     public List<unit_code> unit_codes  { get; set; }
}
public class unit_code
{
     public string unit_code{ get; set; }
     public string unit_code_description  { get; set; }
}
```

I try to return the RestrictionRule class so I start to compose something like

```
var result = (from a in dataset
              group a by new
              {
                a.acct,
                a.dim,
              } into b
              select new RestrictionRule()
              {
                acct = b.Key.acct,
                dims = b.ToList(),
              });
```

At this point, I am not sure why I have exception(Cannot implicitly 'system.collections.generic.list to system.collections.generic.list') against "**dims = b.ToList(),**". Also, since RestrictionRule class has two list(Dim and unit_code) that in hierarcy, please suggest me how I can create it properly. Thank you for everyone's help in advance.

Comment: Example data as an image. Nice and easy to copypaste into LINQpad...

Comment: Thanks for reminder. I just edit it so it's not an image now.

Comment: "I am not sure why I have exception" - what exception? What does "add unit_code information" mean? Add how? Represented how? Used how?

Comment: I just edit my question and hopefully it's helpful.

Comment: So `dims` is of type `List<dim>` (type is key in C#). `b` is of type `IGrouping<Tanon1, Tanon2>` and after the `ToList` you have `List<anon2>`. You can't convert a `List<anon2>` to `List<dim>` implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to group at each level to create the appropriate types:

```
var result = from d in dataset
             group d by d.acct into acctGroup
             select new RestrictionRule {
                acct = acctGroup.Key,
                dims = (from d in acctGroup
                        group d by d.dim into dimGroup
                        select new Dim {
                            dim = dimGroup.Key,
                            unit_codes = (from d in dimGroup
                                         select new UnitCode {
                                            unit_code = d.unit_code,
                                            // unit_code_description = ???
                                         })
                                         .ToList()
                        })
                        .ToList()
             };
```

Answer (score 0):

This LINQ query is not translatable to the SQL. GROUP BY can only return aggregation result and fields which are groping keys. Consider client-side evaluation, because you need all records on the client.

```
var result = from a in dataset.AsEnumerable()
             group a by new
             {
               a.acct,
               a.dim,
             } into b
             select new RestrictionRule()
             {
               acct = b.Key.acct,
               dims = b.ToList(),
             };
```